# MS Access 2010 - make a form populate fields in multiple tables

Tags: database, forms, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am new to access but I have a problem. Take a look at the screenshot of my table relationships. I would like to create a form such that when someone enters the 'Student Code', the student code is populated in all three tables, rather than just one, saving time and confusion as one only needs to type it in once. Thank you everyone in advance. see https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHBqM.png

Comment: The Form setup you need is a Main Form Sub Form. The parent will create a Child, and the Child will create a Medical record for that child. Create a form that contains a subform (a one-to-many form) -  https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Create-a-form-that-contains-a-subform-a-one-to-many-form-ddf3822f-8aba-49cb-831a-1e74d6f5f06b?ui=en-US&rs=en-ZA&ad=ZA

Comment: So if I create that, I can have one field on the form that says 'Student Information' including the student code (what everything is linked by), and then two subforms in there (parent information -one to many, and medical information  - one to one?) Will it automatically create records in the two subform tables using the student code?

Comment: @PaulFrancis even with that set up, the user still needs to enter data in subforms which will automate the linked student code. The OP is thinking triggers which is best translated in Access as automated VBA append queries in an AfterInsert form event.

Comment: How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In the [AfterInsert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff844951.aspx) event of the Student Information form, run append VBA queries. With this, each time you add a new Student record, the corresponding student code will be inserted into the other related tables:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO [Parent Information] (Student Code)" _
              & " VALUES (" & Forms!yourformname![Student Code] & ");"
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO [Student Medical Conditions] (Student Code) " _
              & " VALUES (" & Forms!yourformname![Student Code] & ");"
```

Alternatively, you can save the above queries as stored queries and run them via Macro (Open Query) or VBA (DoCmd.OpenQuery) -both still in AfterInsert form event:

```
DoCmd.OpenQuery "ParentInformationQ"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "StudentMedicalConditionsQ"
```

If your subforms are included on main form, add Requery commands to update subforms. With this, you will see blank rows appear in subforms, ready for data edit (NOT entry since you created the records in prior queries):

```
Forms!yourformname!yourparentinfosubformname.Form.Requery
Forms!yourformname!yourmedicalconditionssubformname.Form.Requery
```